# Send Email with OAuth2 - Server Side Authentication without User Interaction

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal, mailkit

We used so far the Basic Authentication to send an E-Mail with Microsoft office365 from our Server. Now they turned  the Basic Authentication off and only OAuth is working.

I looked around in the internet how I could add the OAuth to our Server and found the following side: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows

My Code looked like this and I got an access token.

```cs
private readonly string[] _scopes =
{
    $"{_emailOption.myUri}/.default"
};

public async Task ActivateOAuth()
{
    _emailoptions.ConfidentialClientApplication = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
        .Create(_emailoptions.ClientId)
        .WithClientSecret(_emailoptions.ClientSecret)
        .Build();

    var authenticationResult = await _emailoptions.ConfidentialClientApplication
        .AcquireTokenForClient(_scopes)
        .WithAuthority(AzureCloudInstance.AzurePublic, _emailoptions.TenantId)
        .ExecuteAsync();

    await SendSuccessfulAuthenticatedEmail(_email.FromAddress, authenticationResult.AccessToken);
}
```

To send now an Email I'm using the MailKit Library, that is able to use the OAuth Authentication. But when I try to `client.AuthenticatAsync(oAuth2)`, the Code always crashes with the error:  `AuthenticationInvalidCredentials: 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful`

```cs
private async Task SendSuccessfulAuthenticatedEmail(string username, string accessToken)
{
    var oAuth2 = new SaslMechanismOAuth2(username, accessToken);

    using var client = new SmtpClient();

    await client.ConnectAsync(_emailoptions.SmtpHost, _emailoptions.SmtpPort, _emailoptions.SmtpSecureOptions);
    await client.AuthenticateAsync(oAuth2); // Here the Code Crashes

    var message = new MimeMessage();
    message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(_emailoptions.FromUserName, _emailoptions.FromAddress));
    message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(_emailoptions.FromAddress, _emailoptions.FromAddress)); 

    var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
    bodyBuilder.TextBody = $"This is the Information, that the OAuth2 is now Activated on ***** Server.{_emailoptions.ServerBase}";
    message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

    await client.SendAsync(message);

    await client.DisconnectAsync(true);
}
```

So I have a access_token from my company App, but it does not work with a specific User to send an E-Mail. But I allowed in the Settings to send an E-Mail:
[image]

So, why is it not Possible to send an E-Mail from a company Account with those settings? And yes the SMTP Authentication is enabled.

**Addition**

If I use the a Code with the following method `_emailoptions.ConfidentialClientApplication.GetAuthorizationRequestUrl(_scopes)`, then copy the Url to a browser and login with the Account and then acquire the token `_emailoptions.ConfidentialClientApplication.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode()`, then i works fine. But I don't want to login after each server restart.

Answer (score 0):

Once your app has been [registered](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app), the tenant admin will need to register your service principal.

To use the New-ServicePrincipal cmdlet, install ExchangeOnlineManagement and connect to your tenant as shown in the following snippet:

```
Install-Module -Name ExchangeOnlineManagement -allowprerelease
Import-module ExchangeOnlineManagement 
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Organization <tenantId>
```

Next, register your the Service Principal for your app:

```
New-ServicePrincipal -AppId <APPLICATION_ID> -ObjectId <OBJECT_ID> [-Organization <ORGANIZATION_ID>]
```

Now you'll need to grant permissions for your app to access the email account.

In order to do that, you'll need to first get the Service Principal ID registered in the previous step using the following command:

```
Get-ServicePrincipal | fl
```

Once you have the Service Principal ID for your app, use the following command to add full mailbox permissions for the email account that your app will be accessing:

```
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity "john.smith@example.com" -User 
<SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID> -AccessRights FullAccess
```